# Command 'find', failed to use '{}' after operartor '>' in Mac OS X

Tags: bash, find, iconv

I am going to convert encoding of some files from GBK to UTF-8.

It is ok to run the following command in Linux:

```
find Bnf -type f -exec iconv -f GBK -t UTF-8 {} -o utf8/{} \;
```

But in Mac OS X, the iconv does not with a -o option, all the output goes to stdout.

So, I changed the command to:

```
find Bnf -type f -exec iconv -f GBK -t UTF-8 {} > utf8/{} \;
```

But the last '{}' was not replaced with the paths of files, but was left literal.

Maybe I could create a bash script to wrapper the iconv and the operator '>', but is there a nicer way to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `>` is getting interpreted by the shell executing `find`. Try escaping it like `\>`.

Comment: @Gabe, thank you for telling me that trick. It helps me a lot to understand my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have better to run iconv out-side of find. And probably, you should run basename.

```
find Bnf -type f |\
while read line; do
  FILE=`basename $line`
  iconv -f GBK -t UTF-8 $line > utf8/$FILE
done
```

And if you want to keep directory structure

```
find Bnf -type f |\
while read line; do
  mkdir -p utf8/`dirname $line` 2> /dev/null
  iconv -f GBK -t UTF-8 $line > utf8/$line
done
```

Comment: Don't do the basename in there, at that point you've modified what the original did.

Comment: @x-istence Why? `find` output "Bnf/foo". Then redirect should be "utf8/Bnf/foo". find does not call mkdir().

Comment: Because basename "Bnf/foo" becomes "foo" so it would store it in utf8/foo, whereas in the find example it would be stored to "utf8/Bnf/foo" (Not sure how the directory gets created ...)

Comment: @x-istence are you ok in above?

Comment: @mattn: You are creating the directory in the same location as it already was, need to prepend utf8 in front of it.